# AWS Lambda skipping records from dynamo DB streams after enabling trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm processing dynamo DB stream records using lambda, the configuration I used for Dynamo DB trigger is as follows:

```
Batch size: 100 Batch window: 0 Starting position: Latest
```

When I enable the trigger after some time a considerable amount of records does not appear in lambda. Is it because of starting position
is set to Latest?.

On further debugging, I found that the records created in the stream in like five minutes differences get processed together, which is not what latest starting position is expected to do.

Please help me with the latest starting position, maybe an official doc or something on how it behaves.